# Not showing collection(s) created on MarkLogic to create layer in Geoserver

Tags: marklogic, geoserver

We don't see any option on to create a new layer in Geoserver. In mongo DB, we use to see the list of collections which have index coord_2dsphere.

Similarly, do we need to create any index on the Geom data. Can anyone point to the doc.

Note: We are able to connect MarkLogic DB through Geoserver.

````
com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: failed to apply resource at resources/geoQueryService: Internal Server Error. Server Message: RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  reason: Extension geoQueryService or a dependency does not exist: XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /marklogic.rest.resource/geoQueryService/assets/resource.xqy not found . See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.checkStatus(OkHttpServices.java:4293)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3290)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3236)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3227)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceServicesImpl.post(ResourceServicesImpl.java:90)
        at com.marklogic.client.impl.ResourceServicesImpl.post(ResourceServicesImpl.java:86)
        at com.marklogic.geotools.basic.GeoQueryServiceManager.getLayerNames(GeoQueryServiceManager.java:40)
        at com.marklogic.geotools.basic.MarkLogicDataStore.createTypeNames(MarkLogicDataStore.java:178)```
````

Comment: The MarkLogic documentation for geospatial search is here --  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/geospatial -- but how that's used in Geoserver seems like a question specific to Geoserver.

Comment: Update the main question. Noticed above exception after going through logs. And also the below error on marklogic server.



```2020-04-22 23:58:53.458 Info: Status 500: RESTAPI-INVALIDREQ: (err:FOER0000) Invalid request:  reason: Extension geoQueryService or a dependency does not exist: XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /marklogic.rest.resource/geoQueryService/assets/resource.xqy not found```

Comment: It looks like you are using some of the community supported tools to connect Geoserver to MarkLogic. Can you provide some more detail on what you have setup? What github project you are using, etc?

Comment: We are using the project marklogic-geotools-plugin to connect to the geoserver.
https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-geotools-plugin

Geoserver version 2.16.1.